# Is there any way to implement numbered pagination instead of PREV | NEXT using JSOM without using search

Tags: list, list-view, caml, csom, list-view-web-part

I'm wondering if there any way to implement Numbered pagination while retrieving items from a list like
"PREV 1,2,3..NEXT" instead of just having "prev | next". I followed this code example [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92) and the "paginationinfo" needs the item ID of the last item while moving to next page. So looks like there is no way to get numbered pagination. Even OOTB list-view web-parts using the same approach, we don't have 1,2,3.. there. I know that we can get it done using search API, but wondering if there is another way to do this by querying list directly. If not, I want to know the reason behind why SharePoint does not support this type of pagination.

Thanks